# Unable to compare dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure-devops

I'm trying to compare the StateChangeDate field having the condition that it should be between the two dates but it's returning 0 as output. Please help to get the output.

method1:

```
date1 = "2023-02-08"
date2 = "2023-05-23"

newdate1 = time.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%d")
newdate2 = time.strptime(date2, "%Y-%m-%d")

df['StateChangeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StateChangeDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['identifier'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if ('Test Case' in row['WorkItemType']) and ('Ready' in row['State'])  and (newdate1 <= row['StateChangeDate'] <= newdate2) else 0, axis=1)

filtered_df = df[df['identifier'] != 0]
filtered_df = filtered_df.reset_index(drop=True)
y1.append(filtered_df.shape[0])
del filtered_df['identifier']
```

method2:

```
df['identifier'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if ('Test Case' in row['WorkItemType']) and ('Ready' in row['State'])  and ('2023-03-22' <= row['StateChangeDate'] <= '2023-04-04') else 0, axis=1)
filtered_df = df[df['identifier'] != 0]
filtered_df = filtered_df.reset_index(drop=True)
y1.append(filtered_df.shape[0])
del filtered_df['identifier']
```

Comment: Try: `df['identifier'] = (df['WorkItemType'].str.contains('Test Case') & df['State'].str.contains('Ready') & df['StateChangeDate'].gt(date1) & df['StateChangeDate'].lt(date2)).astype(int)`

Comment: Tried this but it is still returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
m = (df['WorkItemType'].str.contains('Test Case')
     & df['State'].str.contains('Ready')
     & df['StateChangeDate'].gt(date1)
     & df['StateChangeDate'].lt(date2))

filtered_df = df[m]
```

Comment: Tried this but it is still returning 0.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` please?

Comment: Did you know if at least one condition is true?

Comment: It's sorted. Thanks.